# jQuery Hover Problem

Tags: jquery, css

On my website I have a page with a grid of images. What I want is an image to slide down bigger when it is hovered over, so it gets longer but doesn't move. If that makes sense.

I have the following code, which doesn't work/do anything:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".piece").hover(function () {
        $(this).slideDown(1000, function () {
            $(this).css("height", "250px");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hopefully this question makes sense. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's not a real question and you didn't even think about googling it did you? Would you please create an example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we might help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use the animate function:

```
$(".piece").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).animate({
            height: '250'
        }, 1000);
    }, 
    function() {
        $(this).animate({
            height: '100'
        }, 1000);
    }
);
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Mnf5z/)